# Show time in format like 05:05 am , and store in sqlite database

Tags: android

I want to show time in format like 05:05 am, and store in sqlite database. Please how to store it in db and how to change time format.

Here's my code:

```
edittime.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View 
     final Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
     final int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
     int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
     TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

     mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(CreatNotes.this, new TimePickerDialog.
         @Override
         public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hours, int minutes) {
           String AM_PM = " AM";
           String mm_precede = "";
           if (hours >= 12) {
              AM_PM = " PM";
              if (hours >=13 && hours < 24) {
                 hours -= 12;
              }
              else {
                 hours = 12;
              }
           } else if (hours == 0) {
              hours = 12;
           }
           if (minutes < 10) {
              mm_precede = "
                       edittime.setText( hours  + ":" + minutes +" "+  AM_PM);
                        }
                    }, hour, minute, 
                    mTimePicker.
                }
            } );
```

Comment: You should never store a string in AM/PM format.. you should instead store the time in millis, time in millis is more versatile as it is the base for a date/time.

Answer (score 2):

You should store the date in a db format (UNIX timestamp) and then format it the way you want when you retrieve it from the db.

Comment: how to enter  time in sqlite data base

Answer (score 0):

```
long inputTime;
Calendar mCalendar;
mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

//here is TimePickerDialog

```
new TimePickerDialog(SearchActivity.this, onTimeSetListener,
    mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();


onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int min) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
            inputTime = c.getTime().getTime();
        }
    };
```

//Save this inputTime in your db as long value.

//utility method for format conversion

```
public static String getFormattedTime(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat) {
// Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

// Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

//After read from db, pass the long value(inputTime) to getFormattedTime() method to get formatted Time.

```
String formatedTime = getFormattedTime(inputTime, Constants.TIME_12_HOUR_FORMAT);
```

Comment: i want insert time in data base using timepicker dialogue

Comment: In the timepicker dialogue, user will input time which will be received inside TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() .
using this line, inputTime = c.getTime().getTime(); . The "inputTime" is a long value. You can save it in database.